# how to make an Bootup Application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I want to Make an device policy manager application
in which when i start the application it will have two button one for Guest user and one for Admin User and I will set the password for Admin as Well as Guest login, and after adding both the password when i boot up my device it should show me my main page asking for Admin Login and Guest Loging and when I click on Guest it will as for Guest Password and when I will click on Admin it will as for Admin Password and Unless i Provide any of the password my Device should not go to the home screen and once i have provided the right password it should go to the home screen as in my application i want to bind the use of some application from guest login and from admin login this should be enable.

as in my case i am not able to do so when ever i do so it does only goes to the activity after providing the pass word and once i press the home button it goes to home button

Comment: You cant really do this without modifying Android. The Home button exists to work against your exact usecase.

Comment: Actually, you can. You can register yourself as a launcher. However locking down other way to access settings, notification bar settings and so forth are all difficult hacks.

Comment: hey thanx, i have tried that way as I have register my self as an launcher but still the problem exist,

Comment: Ill Tell now suppose i have made an application which gives me an login screen on start and on providing the password i should go to the home screen of my application but suppose i want to set one default password and one user password in which on default passwor dit will show me my guest login and on user password will show me an  admin login

Comment: in admin login i will have full prevelage and in gust login i wlill restrict the prevelages

Answer (score 1):

root the device and get super user permissions and you can create two users in adb shell command.
sice the os is based on linux its possible but difficult. May be you need to work with the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

1) First you should root the device using the suitable method. For example razorclaw.apk( or which ever suitable for your device).

2) Get the logic to hide status bar. Ex.

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su","-c","service call activity 79 s16 com.android.systemui"});
process.waitFor();
```

3) Write a BroadcastReceiver

```
public class MyBootRecever extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    intent.setClass(context, UserLogin.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

4) Configure the BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="MyBootRecever">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />              
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```